# Failed to resolve type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.IMvxFileStore in iOS

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

After registering File and Json plugins I get "Failed to resolve type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.IMvxFileStore." I am **not** registering a custom MvxFileStore, but the default implementations. 
Reading the documentation once those two plugins are loaded I should get a registered implementation for IMvxFileStore (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#file)

My registration of the plugins is the following:

Bootstrap folder

```
   public class FilePluginBootstrap :
        MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<PluginLoader, Plugin>{}
    public class JsonPluginBootstrap : 
        MvxPluginBootstrapAction<PluginLoader>{}
```

Is there anything I can do to confirm the plugins are loaded? Application Output doesn't show any errors trying to load plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Small but important detail is not to forget to call base.PerformBootstrapActions() in Setup.cs.